# Make a window increase in size using keystrokes

Tags: java

I went with what I could find in java for dummies and what I'm doing isn't working? I'd like a fix and some advice on whether I should focus on simpler things.

this is the code...

```
package frame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;

public class Frame_create {`enter code here`
public static void main(String args[]) {
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame() ;
String myTitle = "blank frame" ;
myFrame.setTitle(myTitle) ;
myFrame.setSize(width, height) ;
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation
(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
myFrame.setVisible(true) ;
}

static int width = 600 ; 
static int height = 200 ;
private Scanner readyread; 



public void input(String args[]){
    readyread = new
    Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNumber = readyread.nextInt();
    int increase = inputNumber*100 ;
    width += increase ;
}}
```

Comment: Keystrokes in the window itself or in the console?

Comment: either... I'm assuming console is the best way to go though...

Comment: console is not the best way to go. Mixing GUI programming and console programming is never the best way to go. See [how to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Matter of fact, maybe you want to go through the entire [How to create GUI with swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or at least start with components and listeners.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: what's wrong with this code specifically, if someone knows?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. If you want to learning GUI programming stay away from the console, look the at the tutorial I linked. Start with Frames, move to Panels, then you Buttons and ActionListeners. That should get a good beginners start.

Comment: what about for game creation? I'm assuming GUI is a big part of game design anyway but should I focus on it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the `input(String args[])` method anywhere? Below is a modification which creates a `Frame_create` object and then calls the the `input` method on it. The `input` method is also changed to take in the `JFrame` object as a second parameter so that the `setSize` method can be called on it again to set the increased width. The number that will denote the increase in size needs to be typed in the console.

```
package frame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;

public class Frame_create {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Frame_create fc = new Frame_create();
  JFrame myFrame = new JFrame() ;
  String myTitle = "blank frame" ;
  myFrame.setTitle(myTitle) ;
  myFrame.setSize(width, height) ;
  myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation
      (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
  myFrame.setVisible(true) ;
  fc.input(args, myFrame);
}

static int width = 600 ; 
static int height = 200 ;
private Scanner readyread; 

public void input(String args[], JFrame myFrame){
    readyread = new
    Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNumber = readyread.nextInt();
    int increase = inputNumber*100 ;
    width += increase ;
    myFrame.setSize(width, height);
  }
}
```

This seems to be working. Hope this helps. Note that if you want to continuously type in a changed size and see the width increase then you will have to put the call to `input` method in a loop.

While this might answer the question, using console and GUI together in this fashion may not be optimal in a real world application.

Comment: If you think this helped you or answered your question please consider accepting it as an answer. Thanks.